# What's the difference between activity diagram and sequence diagram?

Tags: uml

I'm studying UML and I am confused. What's the difference between activity diagram and sequence diagram? I haven't got the crucial point yet.

Comment: See http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html and http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html

Answer (score 48):

They are both behavioral diagrams but have different emphases.

- Activity diagram is good at depicting the control flowing from one activity to another, especially good at the logic of conditional structures, loops, concurrency.
- Sequence diagram is good at depicting the sequence of messages flowing from one object to another, how their messages/events are exchanged in what time-order.

Notice that sequence diagram may also express conditions, loops and concurrency by using guards, but they are not as intuitive and convenient as those in activity diagram.

Answer (score 38):

Activity diagrams represents the flow of use cases. But sequence diagrams represents the interaction between classes or objects according to time.So there is a difference between these two diagrams.

Before moving to activity diagrams you need to draw the use case diagram. using use case(system behaviour) diagram you can identify activities(behaviours).

Then you need to draw the the activity diagram to show the flow of behaviours.

then You need to identify the classes and draw the class diagram.

Using class diagram you can draw the sequence diagrams to show the interaction between classes.

1. use case  diagram
2. activity diagram
3. class diagram
4. sequence diagram

Comment: Hi, I was wondering how confident you are in the validity of this answer? If accurate, it is a quite a succinct and useful summary, however I tend to use caution when things seem too good/easy to be true. It seems to make sense, but I'm still brushing up. Thanks.

Comment: "Using class diagram you can draw the sequence diagrams to show the interaction between classes." Well, you don't really need to carry around the baggage of a full class diagram, shorthand should be sufficient, but I get your point (the classes need to be identified first).

Answer (score 21):

Activity diagram is focused on **Actions** within the behaviour.

Sequence diagram is focused on **Interactions** (communication between objects) within the behaviour.

Comment: same PDF but with searchable text (instead of image pages) https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/asset_files/TechnicalNote/2002_004_001_13934.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the major distinction of a sequence diagram is the *sequential order of information flow as performed by actors in a system*. Activity diagrams place an emphasis on *workflow between activities*.

There's a breakdown on [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-sequence-diagram-and-activity-diagram/).

Answer (score -3):

In general:

- activity diagram - we use it for modeling kod procedures ("steps") (we use activity as abstract steps or task as detailed procedure step)
- interaction diagram - we use it for modeling series of interaction between objects communicate via the interfaces